# Deleting item Displayed in Listview using Button in the ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-button

I have a `ListView` that display items from my database. I successfully displayed it all. And Tried to remove them 1 by 1 using a button inside each list items. At first it seems ok, but then I notice that it doesn't really remove the proper item, But it removes the items from the bottom going up the list. Here is a part my adapter codes. Hope you can help me with this.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final myOrder orderList = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if(convertView == null){


            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

            viewHolder.tableNum = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableNum);
            viewHolder.itemName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            viewHolder.custName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custName);
            viewHolder.itemQuantity = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
            viewHolder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusButton);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.tableNum.setText("Order for Table: "+orderList.getTable_id());
        viewHolder.itemName.setText(orderList.getItem_name());
        viewHolder.custName.setText("Customer Name: " + orderList.getCust_name());
        viewHolder.itemQuantity.setText("QTY: " + orderList.getQuantity());


        if(orderList.getStatus_id() == 1){
            viewHolder.btnStatus.setText("Ready");
            viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Status Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            remove(getItem(position));

                }
            });
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the "remove" and "getItem" methods?

Comment: Shouldn't notifyDataSetChanged() be inside onClick() method?

Comment: i did not create  a remove and getitem method. It is a method already present in the ArrayAdapter

Comment: i tried using getPosition which returns the item index number, but it doesn't allow me to use it inside the remove method, and ask me to create a new remove method with a paramenter of int